How to make svg has a path show outsite the viewBox?
I has a svg as below
Has any way to display 2 circles outside viewBox without change width, height, viewBox?
enter image description here
↓↓↓
enter image description here
<svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 80 80" class="absolute cursor-grab" style="transform:translate(50px, 50px) rotate(0deg);"">
  <defs>
    <path id="mainPath4AS9WoYBM3K2vGQ2" d="M0 0h80v80H0Z"></path>
    <clipPath id="clip4AS9WoYBM3K2vGQ2"><use xlink:href="#mainPath4AS9WoYBM3K2vGQ2"></use></clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g><use xlink:href="#mainPath4AS9WoYBM3K2vGQ2" fill="#f4f1e9" stroke="#cbbda0" stroke-width="4" clip-path="url(#clip4AS9WoYBM3K2vGQ2)"></use></g>

  <path class="absolute" id="subPath4AS9WoYBM3K2vGQ2" fill="#999" d="M72 20a8 8 0 1 0 16 0a8 8 0 1 0 -16 0 M72 60a8 8 0 1 0 16 0a8 8 0 1 0 -16 0"></path>
</svg>


I has only way is change width, height, viewBox
width="88" height="80" viewBox="0 0 88 80"
But it's not good with me

overflow: visible also works for  svg  content.

overflow:visible will generally significantly reduce browser performance. You should really change width/height instead.

Thank you for your help, it's working!
